# Force Chrome to refresh page upon clicking a specific object

Tags: google-chrome, greasemonkey, tampermonkey

Is there a way I can have the browser refresh the entire page when a specific object is clicked?

When I hover over the object Chrome gives me this

```
javascript:submitAction_win0(document.win0,'TERM_CLASSES$tab3$0');
```

on the bottom left hand corner.

I am using Tampermonkey/Greasemonkey to implement.

Answer (score 0):

You probably can get this behavior by attaching your own `onclick` handler to the object that does a `document.location.reload()` or whatever code would cause the page to reload.